# After react-native bump to 71.0, "Cannot find module 'typeorm''

Tags: expo, typeorm, jest-expo

After bumping our expo app to expo SDK 48 (which importantly includes the react-native bump `0.70.13` -> `0.71.0`), when running our previously passing jest suite, we started encounting the error:

"Cannot find module 'typeorm' from '<one of my typeorm objects>.ts'"

It's important to note that our app build still works as expected.

I narrowed down the issue to be only associated w/ the react-native dependency bump, with all relevant expo dependencies on their 48.x versions.

Has anyone else encounted time issue?

Here is my jest configuration in `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@sentry/react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|i18n-js)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ]
  },
```

I've tried many things:

- Updating ignore patterns to include typeorm: `transformIgnorePatterns`
- Experimenting w/ the jest setting 'moduleNameMapper`
- Upgrading to SDK 49 to see if this solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question after hours of debugging.

Included in the [changelog of react native 71.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v0710) is a reference to the `JSCRuntime moved to react-jsc`. I'm assuming this runtime change along with my current configuration is responsible (somehow) for the now inability of jest to retrieve modules.

What ended up working was adding `"testEnvironment": "node"` to our jest config in `package.json`, like so:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@sentry/react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|i18n-js)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ]
  },
```

Why this works, I can only guess, but I hope it helps someone else!